# Can't cross compile c++ class with sqlite included (undefined reference) on linux (i686-w64-mingw32-g++)

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite, cross-compiling

I tried to compile my c++ class with sqltie3 include.
I run Ubuntu 20.04.
For this I use the i686-w64-mingw32-g++ cross compiler, I also tested it with g++ and it works perfectly but not with the i686-w64-mingw32-g++ compiler.

I always get the same error:

```
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: DBWrapper.o:DBWrapper.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: DBWrapper.o:DBWrapper.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
```

My Makefile:

```
mingw       = i686-w64-mingw32-g++
SQLCOMPILE  = -I/usr/local/sqlite/include
CFLAGS      = -Wall
SRCFILES    = *.cpp
OBJFILES    = *.o
TARGETWIN   = progwx.exe

all: $(TARGETWIN)

    
$(TARGETWIN): $(OBJFILES)
    $(mingw) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) $(SQLCOMPILE) -o $(TARGET) -l sqlite3
    
$(OBJFILES): $(SRCFILES)
    $(mingw) $(CFLAGS) $(SQLCOMPILE) -c $(SRCFILES)
    
.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

I put the sqlite source code in $(SQLCOMPILE) and the compiler can include everything unless I call the sqlite3_open() function.
I also compiled the source code to a library (libsqlite3.a) so that the -l tag can find it.
Because the g++ compiler brings also the same "undefined reference" error if I don't put the -lsqlite3 tag in.

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -c sqlite3.c  
$ ar rcs libsqlite3.a sqlite3.o
```

Here is my Headerfile (DBWrapper.h):

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sqlite3.h>

class DBWrapper {
    sqlite3 *db_;
    const int errCode;
public:
    DBWrapper(const std::string &dbname);
    DBWrapper(const DBWrapper&) = delete;
    DBWrapper& operator=(const DBWrapper&) = delete;
    sqlite3* operator*();
    ~DBWrapper();
};
```

Here is my CPP-File (DBWrapper.cpp):

```
#include "DBWrapper.h"


DBWrapper::DBWrapper(const std::string &dbname) : db_(nullptr), errCode(sqlite3_open(dbname.c_str(), &db_)){
    if(errCode) {
        throw std::runtime_error("ERROR at opening database!");
    }
}

DBWrapper::~DBWrapper() {
    sqlite3_close(db_);
}

sqlite3* DBWrapper::operator *() {
    return db_;
}
```

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Can you share your full wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I just needed sqlite3 as a compiled object file (sqlite3.o) for the compiler.